# Is there a way of converting a multi pg PDF into a working Indesign file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, pdf

I have a pdf from the client with over 80 pages in it. I'd like to know if there's a way of converting the PDF into a layered Indd, because working an 80pg booklet on AI is ridiculous and the client doesn't have the working file.

Comment: I'd say your best bet is probably third party plugins, like: [Pdf2id](https://www.recosoft.com/products/pdf2id/) and [pdf2dtp](https://markzware.com/products/pdf2dtp/). I've never converted more than a few pages manually, so I don't really know anything about the troubles these plugins might have.

Comment: This should be posted as an answer as there are really not many alternatives here.

Comment: I've not reputation enough to post it as comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/84483/how-to-place-multi-page-pdf-into-indesign

Answer (score -1):

This was previously asked. Here is [the answer:](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/84483/how-to-place-multi-page-pdf-into-indesign)

It's hidden away but it is possible.

1) File > New > Document

Enter the number of pages of your PDF in "Number of Pages". Deselect "Facing Pages" if you want individual pages. If you know the dimensions of your PDF, set that as your document width and height now, otherwise you can edit it later using File > Document Setup.

2) Window > Utilities > Scripts

Drop down "Application", drop down "Samples" and drop down "JavaScript". Locate "PlaceMultipagePDF.jsx" and double-click it. Locate your PDF and open it. Follow the "OK" prompts and allow it to populate in inDesign.

[image]

Comment: Placing a PDF file into an InDesign document is not the same as turning a PDF file into an InDesign document. The way you’re describing here will not make an editable InDesign document from the PDF file—it will just place individual, uneditable pages of the PDF document as objects on individual InDesign document pages.

Comment: Oh I see - yes this is  not easy as PDFs are designed for output and often contain outlined or encoded text that is not recognized as the same text. I would suggest a plugin but the results may be spotty. Who created the PDF? Is it possible to get the original InDesign (or Quark etc) file?